# How validate method parameters are NotNull by default in spring method validation?

Tags: java, spring, jsr380

[Here](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation-method-constraints) is example about method validation. So check method paramerter as not null I have to write the follolwing:

```
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated

@Validated
public class SomeClass {
    public void myMethod(@NotNull Object p1, @Nullable Object p2) {}
}
```

Is there a way to setup spring bean validation to make all parameters validated as `@NotNull` by default? E.g. the following will fail when `p1` is `null`:

```
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated

@Validated
public class SomeClass {
    public void myMethod(Object p1, @Nullable Object p2) {}
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Reduce annotations on method parameters.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like Spring to automatically validate method arguments do this:

1. add `org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator` to your dependencies
2. mark the required method arguments with `@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull`

then when you call such method and do not provide the required argument you will get a `javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException` exception.

another approach, a lot easier, is to use Lombok's: just mark the method argument with `@lombok.NonNull` and Lombok will do the rest.

Comment: `mark the required methods with ` this what I want to skip regardless of spring or hgibernate validation.

Comment: @Cherry you want all the method arguments to be by default required?

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own `@NotNullArgs` annotation as an option

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface NotNullArgs {
}
```

And aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ArgumentMatcher {

  @Around(value = "@annotation(NotNullArgs)")
  public Object verifyAuthorities(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
     final Optional<Object> nullArg = Arrays.stream(joinPoint.getArgs())
       .filter(Objects::isNull)
       .findFirst();

     if (nullArg.isPresent() && joinPoint.getArgs().length > 0) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException(); // or NPE
     } else {
       return joinPoint.proceed();
     }
  }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
@NotNullArgs
void methodToCall(Obj arg1, Obj arg2) { .... }
```

It's just a draft, but you can use this code as a point to start